# Slick2d - on close

Tags: java

I've recently started playing around with Slick2d in Java. I need to catch an on close event, is there any simple way of doing this with slick2d?

Answer (score 3):

I have done this in my current project that is based on the BasicGame class, by overriding the closeRequested() method, something like this:

```
public class mySmallTestGame extends BasicGame{

.. other code ...

    @Override
    public boolean closeRequested()
    {
      System.exit(0); // Use this if you want to quit the app.
      return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is and old Q&A, but this answer works! Just confirming it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CanvasGameContainer class, which is a java.awt.Canvas. Adding that to a Frame and setting a WindowListener should do the trick.

Comment: If you're calling for an exit routine through one of the implemented methods, you can call "gc.exit();" when gc is your GameContainer Argument.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've understood the question right, but assuming that you're waiting for he user to put in a keyboard stroke or two to end the program you could just put this in the update method.

```
Input input = GameContainer.getInput();
if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_LALT) && input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_F4)){

    System.exit(0);

}
```